How to make this div go to the bottom?
How can I make this div go to the botttom?

Here's the code:
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row customRows">
    <div class="col col-md-3">
        <div class="d-flex mb-4">
            <img src="{% static '/img/cat.png' %}" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid w-25 align-self-center">
            <h1 class="heading-4 align-self-center">Que vamos a estudiar hoy?</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="m-0 p-0">
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                <p class="parrafo menuItem rounded-2 p-2">
                    Inicio
                </p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                <p class="parrafo menuItem rounded-2 p-2">
                    Chat
                </p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                <p class="parrafo menuItem rounded-2 p-2">
                    Ingresa a tu clase
                </p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                <p class="parrafo menuItem rounded-2 p-2">
                    Buscar clases
                </p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                <p class="parrafo menuItem rounded-2 p-2">
                    Calendario
                </p>
            </a>
        </ul>
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="{% static '/img/laying.png' %}" alt="" class="w-75">
        </div>
        <div class="profileContainer row p-2 mt-auto">
            <div class="col-2">
                <img src="{% static '/img/girl3.png' %}" class="w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 my-auto">
                <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                    <p class="parrafo menuItem rounded-2 p-2 m-0">
                        Nombre Usuario
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col col-md-9"></div>
</div>

The things that I've tried are mt-auto class from bootstrap, mb-auto from bootstrap (to check if the ul pushed the container to the bottom), marging-bottom auto in CSS, d-flex and flex-column with flex grow (this kinda worked, but changed the distribution of the content).
.menuItem {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--grisClaro2);
 }

 .menuItem:hover {
  background-color: var(--grisClaro2)!important;
 }

.profileContainer {
 border-top: 1px solid var(--grisClaro2);
}

.customRows {
 height: 100vh;
}


Go down relative to what? (within the viewport or within the whole body or .....)

I added these clases here
        <div class="col col-md-3 d-flex flex-column">

and with mt-auto in the profile container the div went down without ruining the distribution

